# Building/Creating SQL Metrics from the table

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
SELECT  aaa.sr_nbr,
        aaa.inst_nbr,
        bb.country,
        bb.sr_control_type,
        bb.it_tran_code,
        ccc.cust_name,
        ccc.cust_nbr

FROM tablea1 aaa
INNER JOIN tablea2 bb
ON aaa.inst_id=bb.inst_id AND aaa.item_id=bb.item_id

LEFT JOIN table3 ccc
ON bb.inst_id=ccc.inst_id AND bb.item_id=ccc.item_id
WHERE ccc.cust_name NOT LIKE '%EXP%' 
AND ccc.cust_name NOT LIKE '%RMAA%' mt;
```

Now, I have created, separately, queries for metrics, like:

```
SELECT  mt.sr_nbr,
        mt.inst_nbr,
        mt.country,
        mt.sr_control_type,
        mt.it_tran_code,
        mt.cust_name,
        mt.cust_nbr
COUNT(mt.sr_nbr) as cnt_nbr
FROM mt
WHERE mt.it_tran_code <> 'D'
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7;
```

or the another one:

```
SELECT  t_2.sr_nbr,
        t_2.inst_nbr,
        t_2.country,
        t_2.sr_control_type,
        t_2.it_tran_code,
        t_2.cust_name,
        t_2.cust_nbr
        SUM(t_2.sn_dup) AS sn_dup_sum
FROM (
    SELECT
    t_1.sr_nbr,
    t_1.inst_nbr,
    t_1.country,
    t_1.sr_control_type,
    t_1.it_tran_code,
    t_1.cust_name,
    t_1.cust_nbr
    COUNT(t_1.sr_nbr) AS sn_dup
FROM
(
    SELECT 
    mt.sr_nbr,
    mt.inst_nbr,
    mt.country,
    mt.sr_control_type,
    mt.it_tran_code,
    mt.cust_name,
    mt.cust_nbr
    FROM mt
WHERE ccc.cust_name NOT LIKE '%EXP%' 
AND ccc.cust_name NOT LIKE '%RMAA%'

) AS t_1
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
HAVING
COUNT(t_1.sr_nbr) > 1
) AS t_2
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7;
```

and so on... I have about 10 similar metrics.

Now, I do not know the best way how to "put" those query metrics within the main table/query.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert results of a SELECT query into a table if you are able to fill the `INSERT` statement correctly.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, City, Country)
SELECT SupplierName, City, Country FROM Suppliers
WHERE Country='Germany';
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Make sure the amount and types of the results matches the columns you're trying to insert.

Comment: Need to build this within one query.

Comment: What do you mean, please elaborate.

Comment: e.g. all the three queries to write as one. I didn't know how to nest second and third query in the first one, so I wrote them separately.